# Jquery and php wishlist - how to retrieve data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a script that randomly shows divs when you press a button. I would like to make a wish list page in order for people to keep track of what they liked.
I have set a session and a cookie for a day. this is my script and it doesn't work but I'm not sure why... Thanks for all your help.

```
$(".places").hide();

$("#button").click(function(){
    "use strict";
     var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*45);
     var selectedDiv = "#place" + randomNumber;
     $('.places').hide().filter(selectedDiv).show();
     $(".wishlistbutton").click(localStorage.setItem(selectedDiv,JSON.stringify(wishlist)));
});

var wishlistkey = "wishlist";
var wishlist = localStorage.getItem(wishlistkey);

if($.isEmptyObject(wishlist)){
    wishlist = new Array()
} else {
    wishlist = JSON.parse(wishlist);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`$.isEmptyObject`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/) method does not work as you expected since you are providing a string as the argument(expected argument type is a plain JS object), actually which is unnecessary in your code.

```
var wishlist = localStorage.getItem(wishlistkey);
if(!wishlist){
   wishlist = new Array()}
else {
   wishlist = JSON.parse(wishlist);
}
```

Although you need to store the JSON string in localStorage with key as `wishlist` instead of the div id.

```
localStorage.setItem('wishlist', JSON.stringify(wishlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling localStorage setItem and passing in a key, that is the name of the div (selectedDiv), but then you're trying to getItem on a key named "wishlist" Try setting item in storage like this

```
$(".wishlistbutton").click(localStorage.setItem("wishlist", JSON.stringify(wishlist))); });
```

Comment: Is it not the contrary then ? (replacing wishlist with selectedDiv since it is present ? Many thanks

Comment: You need to save the item in localstorage as a key you know ahead of time (here it is "wishlist") The value will then contain the list of divs that they marked as part of their wishlist. So we setItem and pass it a key "wishlist" so we can getItem("wishlist") when we're ready to read our wishlist